# Generating Schema in API documentation with redocly

Tags: documentation, api-doc, redoc, redocly

I am using redocly for generating API documentation. Currently redocly generates API documentation for endpoints (paths), but does not generate schema documentation. [This blog](https://redocly.com/blog/display-schemas/)  on their website explains how to generate the schema section by setting`schemaDefinitionsTagName` value to `Schema` in the configuration file, but it does not seem to be working here.
While I can individually tag each `component/schemas` definition with `<SchemaDefinition schemaRef="#/components/schemas/{SchemaName}" />`  it does not seem to be a scalable solution.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Here is my `.redocly.yaml` configuration file

```yaml
organization: example-org
extends:
  - recommended

apis:
  autopilot@v0.1:
    root: ./api-def.yaml

theme:
  openapi:
    schemaDefinitionsTagName: Schemas
```

This is my `api-def.yaml` file

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.3"

info:
  title: Sample Application
  version: "0.1"

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3000/
    description: localhost
  - url: https://myapp.dev.example.com/
    description: dev server
  - url: https://myapp.qa.example.com/
    description: qa server
  - url: https://myapp.example.com/
    description: prod server

paths:
  /cars:
    post:
      tags:
        - Cars
      operationId: "createCar"
      summary: Create Car
      description: Create a new Car.
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Car"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Car"
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"

  /cars/{id}:
    put:
      tags:
        - Cars
      operationId: "updateCar"
      summary: Update Car
      description: Update an existing car
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Id of the car to be updated.
          schema:
            type: string
            format: objectId
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Car"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Car"
        '400':
          description: Bad Request. The request body has errors.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
        '404':
          description: Not Found. Car with the `:id` parameter not found.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"

    get:
      tags:
        - Cars
      operationId: "getCar"
      summary: Get Car.
      description: Get car represented by id.
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Id of the car to be looked up.
          schema:
            type: string
            format: objectId
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Car"
        '404':
          description: Not Found. Question with the `:id` parameter not found.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"

components:
  schemas:
    Car:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: objectId
        manufacturerId:
          type: string
          format: objectId
        description:
          type: string
          description: detail description of the car
        configuration:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Configuration"
        category:
          type: string
          description: Category of the car
          enum:
            - sedan
            - suv
            - hatchback
            - atv
        createdAt:
          type: string
          format: date
        updatedAt:
          type: string
          format: date
      required:
        - content
        -

    Configuration:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/V6Configuration"
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/V8Configuration"

    V6Configuration:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string

    V8Configuration:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
          
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        code:
          type: number
          description: this would correspond to the HTTP status code of the response.
        description:
          type: string
        data:
          type: object
          description: this object would contain any additional data related to the error.
```

and this is the command I am using to generate the API documentation

```bash
 redocly build-docs --output api-def.html api-def.yaml
```

And this is what generated documentation looks like.
[image: API Documentation Preview]